# Connection reset by peer after fetching file in django

Tags: django, flutter

i'm using django as a backend server and flutter as a mobile app.

when i request a 3d model from my django app the message

```html
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49163)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

but when i open the same file from another online server it works! what should i do?